# Using SharePoint and Microsoft Access Web services as an alternate interface

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sharepoint

I have an application that currently uses Microsoft Access 2013 as a front end with SQL Server 2012 as a back end.  When in the office, that's fine for the users, but some of the users need to be able to access (no pun intended) the application from other sites.

Is it possible to publish the Access front-end to the web while retaining the connection to the back-end tables in SQL Server, and allow the access from SharePoint as an alternate means of getting to the application?

There are firewall issues to contend with, so I was hoping that we'd only have to worry about a firewall opening between the SharePoint server (network A) and the SQL Server (network B).  I'm sorry I can't be more specific than that.

Comment: There is no easy answer to this. You can't just publish Access as a web site. There is little chance you will get an answer as this is so incredibly vague and broad.

Comment: Agree with Sean, way to many variables to consider to provide a good answer.  If there is remote desktop/app capabilities in place that is usually the least amount of rework.

Comment: J.D, is it possible that all your users could have their own local copy of the database? If so, all you may need is some logic that would notify the database users that a new version of the application is now available and force them to update, and also make sure everyone has the same ODBC (DSN, etc.) Connection name and string on their computer.

Comment: Actually, what the client has now said is that the option for off-site access is that each user who needs it will RDP back to their workstation, and fire off the MS Access front end from there.  Thanks for your time on this, I do appreciate it.